# flutter Can't get APK

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, flutter-build

I want to get .apk from my project, but I've got an error from my grade.
I've removed my `.gradle` file and installed it again, but I still can't get .apk.

I've got this :

```
    android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:25: Error: AudioService must extend android.app.Service [Instantiatable]
            <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService"
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    H:\podkadeh\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:35: Error: MediaButtonReceiver must extend android.content.BroadcastReceiver [Instantiatable]
          <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver"      
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       
    
       Explanation for issues of type "Instantiatable":
       Activities, services, broadcast receivers etc. registered in the manifest       
       file (or for custom views, in a layout file) must be "instantiatable" by        
       the system, which means that the class must be public, it must have an
       empty public constructor, and if it's an inner class, it must be a static       
       inner class.
    
    2 errors, 0 warnings
    Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.
    
    To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
    ...
    android {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
            // but continue the build even when errors are found:
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
    ...
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.AndroidLintTask$AndroidLintLauncherWorkAction
       > There was a failure while executing work items
          > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.AndroidLintWorkAction
             > Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 26s
    Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           27.1s
    Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

**Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:**
and I've to use audio service to play audio in the background…

```xml
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.podkadeh">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    
        <application
            android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
            android:label="podkadeh"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
            <activity
                android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    
            <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:required="true"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
        
    
          <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver"
                android:exported="true"
                android:required="true"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    
            <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
                 This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2" />
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

**And here is my `build.gradle`**

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version =  '1.5.0'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }
    
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The example program provided with the library `com.ryanheise.audioservice` that you are including in your project contains a configuration that compiles successfully : https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/blob/minor/audio_service/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` as an attribute in the root node `<manifest>`

Add the attribute `tools:ignore="Instantiatable"` in the `<activity>` node and
`android:exported="true" tools:ignore="Instantiatable"` in the `<service>` and `<receiver>` nodes.